# Create a rainbow color scale based on a vector, in the order of that vector

Tags: r, graphics, colors

I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this:

```
#Create Dataset
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- y*x

#Assign colors, based on z vector    
Data <- data.frame(Order=1:length(z),z=z)
Data <- Data[order(Data$z),]
Data$col <- rainbow(length(z))
orderedcolors <- Data[order(Data$Order),'col']

#Plot x vs y, colored by z
plot(x,y,col=orderedcolors)
```

Basically, I want to assign a color to each point in the `z` vector, and I want those colors to vary on a rainbow scale from z's lowest values to it's highest values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't said how to handle ties, but would this work:

```
plot(x,y,col = rainbow(length(z))[rank(z)])
```

That seems to generate the same output for me, by basically putting the colors in the order of `z` using indexing and `rank`.

Answer (score 11):

Your solution assigns colour to the **rank** of your data. If that's what you had in mind, then that's great.

However, if you really had in mind that the **value** of the data should determine the colour, then here is a solution:

First, your code:

```
#Create Dataset
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- y*x

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#Assign colors, based on z vector    
Data <- data.frame(Order=1:length(z),z=z)
Data <- Data[order(Data$z),]
Data$col <- rainbow(length(z))
orderedcolors <- Data[order(Data$Order),'col']
plot(x,y,col=orderedcolors, main="Yours")
```

Next, my code.  I use the function `colorRamp` that creates function that linearly interpolates between colours given the input to the function.  Since the input to `colorRamp` must be in the range [0; 1], I first define a little helper function `range01` that scales data between 0 and 1.  Finally, since `colorRamp` gives output in RGB values, I use `apply` and `rgb` to get these values back into colours that `plot` understands:

```
range01 <- function(x)(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))
rainbow(7)
cRamp <- function(x){
  cols <- colorRamp(rainbow(7))(range01(x))
  apply(cols, 1, function(xt)rgb(xt[1], xt[2], xt[3], maxColorValue=255))
}  

#Plot x vs y, colored by z
plot(x,y,col=cRamp(z), main="Mine")
```

The results.  Notice the different distribution in colours near the axes.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can just create the rainbow of colors and then index it creatively

```
orderedcolors2 <- rainbow(length(z))[order(order(z))]
```

which gives the same set of colors as your original code

```
> identical(orderedcolors2, orderedcolors)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You say `order(order())`, I say `rank()`. Tomato, tom-ah-to.

Comment: When I saw your answer, I realized that `rank()` made more sense conceptually; I just didn't think of it!